# get empty list when finding last match

Tags: python, regex

I want to find the last word between slashes in a url. For example, find "nika" in "/gallery/haha/nika/7907/08-2015"

I wrote this in my python code:

```
>>> text = '/gallery/haha/nika/7907/08-2015'
>>> re.findall(r'/[a-zA-Z]*/$', text)
```

but I got an empty list:

```
[]
```

And if I delete that dollar sign:

```
>>> re.findall(r'/[a-zA-Z]*/', text)
```

The return list is not empty but '/haha/' is missed:

```
['/gallery/', '/nika/']
```

Anybody knows why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use *lookarounds* as in

```
re.findall(r'(?<=/)[a-zA-Z]*(?=/)', text)
```

[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/sS2dM8/18#python)

---

`$` means end of string so you are getting empty string.

`haha` is missing because you are capturing `/` and so `/` is not left for  `haha`. When you use lookarounds it is a *0 width assertion* and it does not consume `/` and so all are captured.

Comment: thank you, and do you know how to find the last match?

Comment: @KingstonChan `(?<=/)[a-zA-Z]*(?=/)(?!.*/[a-zA-Z]*/)` see demo https://regex101.com/r/sS2dM8/19

Comment: @KingstonChan, or `matches[-1]`.

Comment: vks, Use italics for emphasis instead of code blocks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex for this,

```
>>> s = "/gallery/haha/nika/7907/08-2015"
>>> for i in reversed(s.split('/')):
    if i.isalpha():
        print(i)
        break


nika
```

or

```
>>> [i for i in s.split('/') if i.isalpha()][-1]
'nika'
>>>
```

or

```
>>> j = s.split('/')
>>> [i for i in j if i.isalpha()][-1]
'nika'
```

Comment: Nice to see that [Avinash Raj](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/133/regex?userid=3297613) is giving Non-regex answers

Comment: @BhargavRao regex answer is already given so we must do the opposite role :-)

Answer (score 2):

> I want to find the last word between slashes...

To get the last... you can always throw a [greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) [dot](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) before to ᗧ eat up:

```
^.*/([a-zA-Z]*)/
```

And [capture](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) wanted stuff to `$1`. See [test at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nA3bX2/1)

Comment: with `re.findall` it will give the desired result